# Get row elements without using "closest" selector - jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with 4 columns . 4th column is a button (not shown in below code). When I click on the button in a row, I want to get row elements.

I have done it using **closest** selector. Is there any way to find table row element **"Without using closest"**. This is the requirement for some reason.

> Please assume there is a button at end of each row

```
<table id="food">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>                         
        </tr>                           
    </thead>    
    <tbody> 
        <tr class='details'>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='details'>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Mango</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class='details'>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Grape</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the existing code, I need to replace closest. It will be awesome if I can use class names like `$(this).somethin('.details');`

```
 $('#button1').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');    
    //Do some stuff
})
```

Thanks

Comment: _"This is the requirement for some reason"_ Um, care to share the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**parents()**](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) and pass a class selector like

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
    var row = $(this).parents('.details');    
    //Do some stuff
})
```

Note, you could also use closest in this case and pass the class selector

```
var row = $(this).closest('.details');
```